# How to append rows with concat to a pandas DataFrame using a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to add rows to an existing Dataframe, one by one.
If I use `append`, I got this warning:

```
main.py:41: FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
  df_html_consolidate = df_html_consolidate.append(row_html_good, ignore_index=True)
```

I have the following for loop:

```
df_html_consolidate = pd.DataFrame()
for _, row_html_good in df_html_good.iterrows():
    canonical = str(row_html_good['Canonical Link Element 1'])

    if "/" in canonical and canonical != row_html_good['Address']:
        row_html_good['Address'] = canonical

    consolidate_mappings[row_html_good['Address']] = row_html_good['Address']

    df_html_consolidate = df_html_consolidate.append(row_html_good, ignore_index=True)
```

What is the best way to do this `concat`?

Comment: did you look in the official documentation ? [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) you find one example for concatenating of two dataframes with exact same columns. That is what you want to do, right ?

Comment: Not exactly. Initially, `df_html_consolidate ` is empty.  In for loop, I want to add row `row_html_good `, from another Dataframe, which can be modified.

Comment: What have you attempted to do with `concat` so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of appending in a loop, you could store them in a list, construct a DataFrame and `concat`:

```
lst = []
for _, row_html_good in df_html_good.iterrows():
    canonical = str(row_html_good['Canonical Link Element 1'])

    if "/" in canonical and canonical != row_html_good['Address']:
        row_html_good['Address'] = canonical

    consolidate_mappings[row_html_good['Address']] = row_html_good['Address']
    lst.append(row_html_good)

df_html_consolidate = pd.concat([df_html_consolidate, pd.DataFrame(lst)])
```

If you want to append just one row, you could use `loc`:

```
df.loc[len(df)] = a_list # the length of the list must match the number of columns
```

or

```
df.loc[len(df)] = pd.Series(a_list, index = df.columns)
```

or

```
df.loc[len(df)] = dict(zip(df.columns, a_list))
```

Note that your code doesn't seem to need to be looped. Maybe something like the following could do the job:

```
msk = (df_html_good['Canonical Link Element 1'].astype(str).ne(df_html_good['Address']) & 
       df_html_good['Canonical Link Element 1'].astype(str).str.contains('/'))
df_html_good['Address'] = np.where(msk, df_html_good['Canonical Link Element 1'].astype(str), df_html_good['Address'])
```

Comment: See in [pandas.DataFrame.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html), the signature for `DataFrame.where()` differs from `numpy.where()`. Roughly `df1.where(m, df2)` is equivalent to `np.where(m, df1, df2)`.